# How to debug "Failed to open zip file" in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

It shows the following error:

> Error:Failed to open zip file.
>   Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>   1:build.gradle

Comment: Are you trying to build project offline?

Comment: Yes i have been using it in offline mode..

Comment: For the first sync you need to have active internet connection, because Android Studio downloads required Gradle files.

Comment: Also, use a title that describes the problem

Comment: Please read error log carefully before posting here.- it is clearly mentioned in error that it requires network.

Comment: I had this similar problem. [Here's a link to the two perfect answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416840/there-is-no-android-device-showing-in-my-android-studio/45417586#45417586)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was facing the same issue. Few points you can verify :

1. It may be your internet connection issue so check your internet connection is working well.
2. This can be solve by Perform invalidate cache/ Restart
3. If above 2 options are not wokring you need to reload the the dependencies so perform `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/` and `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`.

Perform these both commands and reverify your gradle path. This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, just connect to internet and sync again build.gradle file.